# multicast and iptables : troubleshooting?

Tags: iptables, multicast

I have secured a linux box, starting with

```
iptables -P INPUT DROP
iptables -P OUTPUT DROP
iptables -P FORWARD DROP
```

and after adding rules to enable specific protocols and streams.

- Which are the correct rules to add multicast support ?

I am trying with these - for both client and server multicast :

```
iptables -A INPUT  -m pkttype --pkt-type multicast -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -m pkttype --pkt-type multicast -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT  --protocol igmp -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT --protocol igmp -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT  --dst "224.0.0.0/4" -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT --dst "224.0.0.0/4" -j ACCEPT
```

Linux 2.6.38-12 / iptables 1.4.10

- Is there any internet service to test my multicast set ( pc + adsl router + provider ) ?

Comment: It would be helpfull to tell us which version of netfilter/iptables do you use. If you use the distro standard, please let us know, which linux distro including version information do you use.

Comment: Done. Also with a new, related, question.

Answer (score 1):

multicast over the global internet does not exist, it is unicast only.

If you wish to test multicast addresses, configure it within your own network.

Comment: This info is incorrect. multicast works over WAN and internet, your provider have to enable and configure the routers.

Comment: right, via peerings to participants in the multicast group. my point still stands that the Internet as a whole does not have multicast.

Comment: Ok, but you don't answer my question about iptables.

Comment: matching on a packet type of "multicast" is sufficient depending on what overall ruleset you have configured iptables with; if all your chains are set to ACCEPT, obviously you don't need any rules at all.